# Missing firmware iwlwifi

Tags: 12.04, iwlwifi, alternate

I need to install Linux, better Ubuntu, to my 4 GB flash-drive. As 4 GB is too small for normal desktop version of Ubuntu I have downloaded `alternate` version through [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) because of recomendation from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55984/full-install-ubuntu-on-4gb-usb-drive). But there are few problems with installation. Almost at the start of the process it shows up first error:

```
Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate.  The firmware can be loaded from
removable media, such as a USB stick or floppy.

The missing firmware files are: iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode

If you have such media available now, insert it, and continue.
Load missing firmware from removable media?
```

After which was second error:

```
The missing firmware files are: rtl_nic/rtl8411-3.fw
```

I have found some useful information  about this [on the internet](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/how-to-provide-non-free-firmware-files-to-the-debian-jessie-installer-4175542680/), but thats all I found. In that topic author uses debian and debian commands, so I can't use it personally. But I have downloaded `firmware-iwlwifi_0.43_all.deb` and can not unpack it.

---

Any ideas how to fix this?

Laptop: Dell Vosto 5470.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iwlwifi firmware pertains to your wireless card. Go here:

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html

And download the correct 7260 driver. Unzip the .ucode files and put them on a usb. You can also skip the error and later put the .ucode files into /lib/firmware.

The second error pertains to your Ethernet port. You can also skip that error, download the drivers here:

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-realtek

and place the correct .fw files within the /lib/firmware folder.

Also, which version are you installing? 16.04 should have full support for the 2 previous devices.

--upvote if this helped :)--

Comment: I'll try right now. There is no alternate version 16.04, only 12.04.5. With 16 everything worked, except there was not enaugh space on flash-frive.

Comment: You don't need the alternate for a full install on a USB. You should be able to install on a USB just like any other storage medium. I did it on my 16GB Sandisk Ultra Fit. Just disable journaling and swap.

Comment: I have 4GB flash drive. When I was trying to install ubuntu-desktop 16.04 on it I got error "not enaugh space". Is there really any chance to make it work though?

Comment: And btw, how I should install second archive for Ethernet port? It is `.deb`, so I cant open it with standart commands. And the last thing. How to insert these drivers to Ubuntu? Any command or it will do that automatically?

Comment: Unpack it on a separate computer, or skip the error and install later. The Ethernet and Wifi errors aren't crucial to the installation. I would install something other than Ubuntu on a 4GB flash drive. Slax comes to mind. 4GB will be very tight, especially under Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah. Looks like it will be many problems with ubuntu on such a small drive. Can you name few more OS? I need something similar to Ubuntu to make myself understand at least something :)

Comment: Slax, Puppy Linux, etc. If you really want Ubuntu/Debian, install it as a Live CD on a USB, and then enable persistence. Guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

Comment: The thing is I want to make a drive with fully working Linux on it. It should be comfortable for me to use it if there is no other system on PC. But I don't need just liveCD(liveUSB), I need it to save some data(like small text-files) on the same drive. Thats why Slax right now looks pretty promising.

Comment: I think I'll chose Slax, so the question is no more relevant and closed.

Comment: That's what persistence does. Persistence allows you to save files and data on the drive.

Answer (score 1):

The package `linux-firmware` contains the file: `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode`

If you have ethernet setup, then do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

If not download the [deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-firmware&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) file. Make sure that you choose the correct distribution version.

Then,

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

BTW Debian commands do work in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

First run `dmesg` in the terminal to get diagnostic data as follows.

```
┌──(rootkali)-[~]
└─# dmesg
Then you will get missing firmware failed to load  highlighted in red as
[   13.491010] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[   13.491013] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
```

Copy the firmware info after failed to load (iwl-debug-yoyo.bin) in this case.

Then enter this command followed by the missing firmware you copied from above like this:

```
┌──(rootkali)-[~]
└─# apt-cache search iwl-debug-yoyo.bin
firmware-nonfree-contrib..............90393jklflsdk
```

Then you get this.
Finally, install that firmware by running this command/

```
┌──(rootkali)-[~]
└─# apt install firmware-misc-nonfree........-090-9-0sdlf
```

Don't forget to replace firmware-misc-nonfree with what you obtained by following the procedure.